# jQuery Change slider values respectively

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I create 3 slider, [Slider 1, Slider 2, Slider 3], and they work fine individually. but I want to make them depend on each other and work respectively to main slider.

You can see my demo here : [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tutorialdrive/xGL8L/)

Main slider is Slider 1, and other slider 2 and slider 3 are depend on slider 1.
If slider 1's value increase (when we slide slider) then slider 2's and slider 3's value should increase too. and same as with when we decrease value.

Second point : If we set slider 1 to 100 and then slider 2 and 3 also on value of 100 (Automatically), then 100 is min. value of slider 2 and 3. in short value of slider 1 is minimum value of slider 2 and 3.

For Example is slider 1 set to 500 then slider 2 and 3 can slide to increase to more then 500 but can not decrease lower then 500.

here is a sample of my code

```
<div id="slider1"></div><br>
<div id="slider2"></div><br>
<div id="slider3"></div><br>
Slider 1 : <div id="value1"></div><br>
Slider 2 : <div id="value2"></div><br>
Slider 3 : <div id="value3"></div><br>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider1" ).slider({
      value:100,
      min: 0,
      max: 500,
      step: 50,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
         $( "#value1" ).text(ui.value);
         $( "#slider2" ).slider('option',{min: ui.value});  
        $( "#slider2" ).slider('value',ui.value);
        $( "#slider3" ).slider('option',{min: ui.value});
      }
    });
  });

$(function() {
    $( "#slider2" ).slider({
      value:100,
      min: 0,
      max: 500,
      step: 50,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
          $( "#value2" ).text(ui.value);
          $( "#value2" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider2" ).slider( "value" ) );
        $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
      }
    });
  });

$(function() {
    $( "#slider3" ).slider({
      value:100,
      min: 0,
      max: 500,
      step: 50,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
          $( "#value3" ).text(ui.value);
          $( "#value3" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider3" ).slider( "value" ) );
        $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `min` option from slider.
Use `return false` on slide event when the value will be lower than `slider1`

[Example in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sV9EV/2/)

Full code:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider1" ).slider({
      value:100,
      min: 0,
      max: 500,
      step: 50,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#value1" ).text(ui.value);
        $('#value2').text(ui.value); // slider 2 text
        $('#value3').text(ui.value); // slider 3 text
        $( "#slider2" ).slider('value',ui.value);
        $('#slider3').slider('value',ui.value);
        //$( "#slider2" ).slider('option',{min: ui.value});  remove this
        //$( "#slider3" ).slider('option',{min: ui.value});
      }
    });


    $( "#slider2" ).slider({
      value:100,
      min: 0,
      max: 500,
      step: 50,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
          if(ui.value < $('#slider1').slider('value')){ // if the value is lower than slider 1
              return false; // don't slide
          }
          $( "#value2" ).text(ui.value);
          $( "#value2" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider2" ).slider( "value" ) );
          $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.value );

      }
    });

    $( "#slider3" ).slider({
      value:100,
      min: 0,
      max: 500,
      step: 50,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
          if(ui.value < $('#slider1').slider('value')){ // if the value is lower than slider 1
              return false; // don't slide
          }
          $( "#value3" ).text(ui.value);
          $( "#value3" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider3" ).slider( "value" ) );
          $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I made some change to your code. 
Basically, setting the min value will not alwas change the slider position, you are juste setting the value when the slider is all left. In the example the slider 2 set it's min value depending on the current slider1's value. The slider 3 is setting it's min showed value the depending on the current slider1's value.

You can optimize a little bit but I think this is what you want to achieve !

```
//min value of slider 2 = current value of slider 1
$( "#slider2" ).slider('option',{min: ui.value});
//slider 3 cannot be under slider 1
if($( "#slider3" ).slider("value") < ui.value)
    $( "#slider3" ).slider('option',{value: ui.value});
```

[Check it here](http://jsfiddle.net/j4RDJ/1/)

Comment: Its Done, what i want is you can see in accepted answers, but I appreciate you help. thanks

Answer (score 1):

it's a bit messy...anyway i hope this could help you out:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider1" ).slider({
      value:100,
      min: 0,
      max: 500,
      step: 50,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
         $( "#value1" ).text(ui.value);
         if(ui.value%100 == 0)
         {
          $( "#slider2" ).slider('option',0);  
        $( "#slider2" ).slider('value',0);
        $( "#slider3" ).slider('option',0);
         }
         else{
           $( "#slider2" ).slider('option',{min: ui.value});  
        $( "#slider2" ).slider('value',ui.value);
        $( "#slider3" ).slider('option',{min: ui.value});
         }

      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Its Done, what i want is you can see in accepted answers, but I appreciate you help. thanks

Answer (score 0):

just to highlight an important point, I have just realized it accepts ONLY Integer values on this command:

```
$( "#slider2" ).slider('value',IntValue);
```

So, if you needed to change its value by passing input text, then you must cast it this way:

```
parseInt($("#input_text_slider2").val())
```

so you are able to put that value using the variable `IntValue` above.